# Encrypt/Decrypt AES/GCM/NoPadding from JAVA to PHP(A tag should be provided)

Tags: java, php, aes

I have this code in java

```
String data = "private-key";
System.out.println("data: " + data);

//create Cipher
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");

//generate key
KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGenerator.init(256);
SecretKey skey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
System.out.println("skey: " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(skey.getEncoded())));

//generate iv
byte[] biv = new byte[12];
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
random.nextBytes(biv);
System.out.println("biv: " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(biv)));

//init
GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, biv);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey, spec);

//encrypt
byte[] encryption = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
byte[] be = Base64.getEncoder().encode(encryption);
System.out.println("encryption: " + new String(be, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

//decrypt
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey, spec);
byte[] decryption = cipher.doFinal(encryption);
System.out.println("origin: " + new String(decryption, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

And I want to translate this code in PHP(I want to share infos between java app and php app).

In PHP I managed this:

```
$data = "private-key";

$skey = random_bytes(32);
$biv = random_bytes(12);

//encrypt
$encryption = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-128-gcm', $skey, OPENSSL_NO_PADDING, $biv);
echo "encryption: " . base64_encode($encryption) . "<br>";

//decrypt
$origin = openssl_decrypt($encryption, "aes-128-gcm", $skey, OPENSSL_NO_PADDING, $biv);
echo "origin: " . $origin;
```

But I get error in PHP at `openssl_encrypt`:
`Warning: openssl_encrypt(): A tag should be provided when using AEAD mode` and I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: During decryption, GCM uses a tag for authenticity checking that is implicitly generated during encryption. In the Java code, ciphertext and tag are automatically concatenated (ciphertext|tag). In the PHP code, the tag must be handled explicitly: It can be retrieved via the 6th parameter in `openssl_encrypt()` and specified during decryption with `openssl_decrypt()`.

Comment: @Topaco, What if I encrypt in Java and after I want to decrypt in PHP. How I can create this tag. Or in reverse, encrypt in php and decrypt in java.

Comment: As already mentioned, the tag is *automatically* generated during encryption and implicitly concatenated in the Java code: ciphertext|tag. Since ciphertext and tag are handled separately in the PHP code, both parts must therefore be separated there. The tag is the last 16 bytes. Then ciphertext and tag must be passed individually as the 1st and 6th parameters in `openssl_decrypt()`. Conversely, ciphertext and tag from the Python code must be concatenated for decryption with the Java code.

Comment: @Topaco, I have encrypted my data in Java, and after I went to PHP to decrypt. Have split by your logic, but I receive an empty string after decryption. Can you give me some code/steps example, when you have time?

Comment: @Topaco, I found it. The problem was that in PHP it was used "aes-128-gcm", while in Java I was using 256 version. Thank you for help

Comment: Another flaw, but without impact, is the use of `OPENSSL_NO_PADDING`. This flag is only intended in the context of *asymmetric* encryption and corresponds numerically to the combination `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING | OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` in the context of *symmetric* encryption. `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` disables padding (which you probably wanted to achieve with `OPENSSL_NO_PADDING`) but does not need to be set as it is *implicitly* set for a stream cipher like GCM, `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` disables the default Base64 encoding/decoding.